# rebind jquery elements in partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, binding, partial-views

I am working with MVC with jquery.

I have an input form that uses jquery for client side functionality such as validating dropdowns etc.

When the for is posted to the server, a partial view is returned.

The question I have is how do I re bind the partial view when its returned from the server?

Comment: Do you have some code we could look at?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use jQuery's `.on()` method in order to bind the events to newly-created elements. Here is the doc: http://api.jquery.com/on/